# No result for SARIMAX

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

I'm working on a project to analyse how covid 19 affects shipment volume and I'm using SARIMAX to predict the shipment volume for the next few months. However, I keep getting the results as shown below :

```
   # Shipment volume data (monthly basis)
  
    df_monthly = df.loc[:'2020-06-30'].resample('MS').sum()
    df_monthly


   # covid 19 data (monthly basis)
     
     df_covid_monthly = df_covid.loc[:'2020-06-30']
     df_covid_monthly = df_covid.resample('MS').sum() 
     df_covid_monthly 

  
   # SARIMAX model
     
     model= SARIMAX(df_monthly, exog=df_covid_new, order=(2,1,1), enforce_invertibility=False, 
           enforce_stationarity=False)

     results= model.fit()

    # Prediction

    pred =  results.get_prediction(start='2020-06-01',end='2020-12-01',dynamic=False, index=None, 
    exog=df_covid_monthly['2020-02-01':], 
     extend_model=None, extend_kwargs=None)
    pred
```

output :

```
<statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.PredictionResultsWrapper at 0x27b64b4a608>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause but I noticed that the 3rd last line has a date that is not in the range specified. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: The data I'm having for covid 19 is only starting from 1/2/2020-1/6/2020 . I noticed when I don't specify the data range I will be getting  ValueError: Provided exogenous values are not of the appropriate shape. Required (6, 1), got (42, 1).

Comment: So why are you specifying a date range that is not in the data range? Wouldn't it be more correct to change your start to 2020-02-01 and your end to 2020-06-01? (Note I am assuming your dates are in the format dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: I wanted to predict the shipment volume for the next few months. How should I do instead because I'm kinda new to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many readings and attempts on modifying my codes, I'm finally able to get the result for my prediction. Here's the changes I made:
`model = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(endog=df_monthly, order=(1,1,1),seasonal_order=(0,1,1,12))`

`model_fit = model.fit()`

`prediction = model_fit.predict(start='2020-07-01',end='2020-1201',dynamic=False,  exog=df_covid_monthly,extend_kwargs=None)`

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected output. You need to access properties off of `PredictionResultsWrapper` such as `predicted_mean`.

See the development documentation: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.base.prediction.PredictionResults.html

Note that you won't see the `Wrapper` since this is just a class that attaches indices and does housekeeping. `PredictionResults` is the main class returned.